# Parallel tasks in Gradle not finishing (connectedAndroidTest)

Tags: android, google-app-engine, gradle, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-endpoints

I have `org.gradle.parallel=true` on in `gradle.properties`. I'm running a backend Google Cloud module and in parallel a connectedAndroidTest that carries out some Espresso testing. The testing is successful and the tasks are OK in green (See image), but the connected test task never actually finishes itself or prints the line and it doesn't move on to the next task in the queue.

If I run the task on its own it ends and prints the line.

My root build.gradle file:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()
    }
}

// Task to set up GCE, runs paid flavor test and shuts down the server.
task configureTest {
    dependsOn 'startBackend', 'runInstrumentedTest', 'stopBackend'
    doLast {
        println 'Tests carried out and local server shut down'
    }
}

task startBackend {
    dependsOn ':backend:appengineRun'
}

// Run InstrumentedTest only in paid flavor as there is no interstitial ad.
task runInstrumentedTest {
    mustRunAfter 'startBackend'
    dependsOn ':app:connectedPaidDebugAndroidTest'
    doLast {
        println 'The test finished.'
    }
}

task stopBackend 
    mustRunAfter 'runInstrumentedTest'
    dependsOn ':backend:appengineStop'
}
```

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To avoid any block, Please try to start the backend in daemon mode and see if it will help you to complete the test correctly. To be able to do that, add the following on your backend's `build.gradle` file:

```
    task startBackend {
        project(":backend").afterEvaluate { backend ->
            backend.extensions.appengine.daemon = true
        }
        // ...
    }
```

Se the following post for more information:

- [Android gradle task Google Appengine](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31441508/3346625)